# capture image in low resolution on newer OS versions

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm trying to capture an image in Android. My code works fine in KitKat, and the image is good resolution, but on Android versions newer than KitKat I have a problem where the image is low resolution.

This is my code:

```
if (isKitKat_or_older && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            takenImagePath = getOriginalImagePath();
            Mybitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(takenImagePath);
            iv_ad.setImageBitmap(Mybitmap);
            save_into_sharedpref();

            //Toast.makeText(Upload_ad.this, selectedFilePath_image1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (newer_than_kitkat && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            try {
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                Mybitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                iv_ad.setImageBitmap(Mybitmap);
                save_into_sharedpref();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

Comment: my question is good .. where is the problem

Comment: please help me to find sol

Comment: ???? I see no question to begin with.